# Position during Animation rotate android

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I'm doing an application game. I have a framelayout rotating by Animation Rotate.
The framelayout got some Imageviews within. I'm interested to know what the position of the Imgaevies in every moment during the rotartion.
Right now it gives me back the initial position in the image before the rotate happened.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Setup and use of the Animation:

```
private Animation animRotate;
this.animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.imageviewlayout);
fl.startAnimation(animRotate);
ImageView mimage=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image);
mimage.setOnClickListener(this);
```

This is the rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
<rotate
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="800"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:duration="4500"/>
</set>
```

The onclick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    float[] locations ={0,0};
    locations[0] = v.getX();
    locations[1] = v.getY();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"x= "+locations[0]+"y = "+locations[1] + "pressed "+!!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Comment: if you use Animation the position doesn't change at all when animating, you should use Animator framework instead (ObjectAnimator with "rotation[X|Y]" property)

Comment: I have not found a good link example I  would be hppay write down what you know

Comment: what did you use when asking google?

Comment: how to use  Animator framework

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=Android+animator+framework

Comment: First of all, thank you very much it helped! I want to rotate the object in the form of a circle but it turns really not nice Do you know what values should be within the creature of an object that will give me  a  beautiful circle?

Comment: FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.imageviewlayout);
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fl, "rotation", 0,360);
        animation.setDuration(4000);
        animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start();

Comment: This is what exists at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That helped me!**

```
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.imageviewlayout);      
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fl, "rotation", 0,360); 
animation.setDuration(4000); 
animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE); 
animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()); 
animation.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact rotate angle during the rotate animation called:

```
yourimageview.getRotation();
```